# Combining arrays based on array values?

Tags: php

I have an array of images:

```
array(
    array('title'=> 'img_one', 'width' => 100),
    array('title'=> 'img_two', 'width' => 200)
    //etc
)
```

I also have an array of widths and heights.

```
array(
    array('w'=>100, 'h' => 100),
    array('w'=>200, 'h' => 999)
)
```

I need to run through the first array and where a width matches in the first and second array, add the height to the first array, so I get something like:

```
array(
    array('title'=> 'img_one', 'width' => 100, height=>100),
    array('title'=> 'img_two', 'width' => 200, height=>999)
)
```

Other than the obvious creating a loop and checking values against values, is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: There is an infinite number of possible solutions, but I'd start with a loop and refactor if you find any problems with that solution.

Comment: nope, you have to use loop. If root keys wouldnt be numeric you could use `array_merge_recursive`

Comment: or maybe use a combination of array_walk and array_search ;) but I don't see a reason against using loops.

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution for PHP 5.5+:

```
$map = array_column($widthsHeights, 'h', 'w');
$images = array_map(function (array $image) use ($map) {
    return $image + ['height' => $map[$image['width']];
}, $images);
```

Assumes that all possible widths have an entry in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to this problem is:

```
$images = array(
    array('title'=> 'img_one', 'width' => 100),
    array('title'=> 'img_two', 'width' => 200)
);

$sizes = array(
    array('w'=>100, 'h' => 100),
    array('w'=>200, 'h' => 999)
);

foreach($images as &$image) {
    foreach($sizes as $size) {
        if ($image['width'] == $size['w']) {
            $image['height'] = $size['h'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $images = array(
            array('title'=> 'img_one', 'width' => 100),
            array('title'=> 'img_two', 'width' => 200)
        );


$sizes = array(
    array('w'=>100, 'h' => 100),
    array('w'=>200, 'h' => 999)
);
$order=0;

foreach($images as &$image) {

       $image['height'] = $sizes[$order]['h'];


$order++;
    }
```